# Can Tornado route differently based on Content-Type header?

Tags: python, tornado

For the very same REST route, e.g. `/message`, can I configure routing to execute different handlers based on the value of the `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 1):

No. Tornado's routing only considers the hostname and path. You'll have to route this path to a single `RequestHandler` and then inspect the `Content-Type` inside that handler.